ASP.NET Core Identity and MAUI - External Provider - Retrieve Access Tokens
I have a MAUI application which needs to authenticate to Google via a ASP.NET Core Web API.
I have no problem with internal users (i.e. which doesn't need to authenticate via Google), I call the native /Login endpoint, and I get a correct access token.
I have followed this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows
And more precisely, in the backend, I have implemented this controller:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Essentials/samples/Sample.Server.WebAuthenticator/Controllers/MobileAuthController.cs
When the user logs in, the code goes inside the "else", so the authentication with Google is OK, I can retrieve access token and other information, but what I need is to get the access token for my application (not this by Google), if I get the access token from Google, I get an "Unauthorized" response when calling my endpoints.
I want to do what he is said in the notes : "To obtain a token you can use to authorize web requests to the web backend itself, you should create your own token in your web app, and return that instead. The Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication has more information about advanced authentication scenarios in ASP.NET Core."
So my question: how to generate/retrieve the access_token (and refresh_token) for a user?

You can try generating an access token for the application and sending it back to the client, for example, by using the new token in the "access_token" field of the qs dictionary. Make sure to configure the JWT key and other related information in appsettings.json, and ensure that the client uses the new access token for subsequent API calls.
